# Template argument inference in D

Tags: templates, d

I am writing some vector functions which operate on static D arrays like so:

```
real[N] unit(uint N)(real[N] v) {
    real[N] u = (v[] / norm(v)); //explicit type necessary to force slice-operator
    return u;                    //to return static-length array
}

real[3] v = unit!(3)([1,2,3]);   //works
real[3] w = unit([1,2,3]);       //error, compiler doesn't infer the template parameter
real[3] x = [1,2,3];
auto i = unit(x);                //also works, forces statically allocated array
```

So, my question is, is there a way to get the compiler to infer the template parameter N if I pass a literal array directly to the function? I tried using "1.0L" format, in the hopes that the array was being cast from a static array of int or float, but that didn't work either.
**TL;DR Can I make the middle example (w) above work?** Thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify, I've tried a few variations with specialized template parameters, but I'm not sure I've done that correctly. I have also tried, in the call, `new real[3]([1,2,3])` to force a heap allocated static array (a three horned unicorn?) but I couldn't get that to compile.

Comment: ant if you complicate the arg a bit `real[N] unit(uint N,T:real)(T[N] v)` I made the real in the arg

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks for the suggestion, I've played with specialization a bit, and can't seem to make it work. I am using dmd 2.058, and the signature you posted gives me template unit(uint N, T:real) does not match any function template declaration.

Comment: what does `real[3] w = unit([1.0,2,3]);` give?

Comment: @BCS Unfortunately the same "does not match" error. I have absolutely fallen in love with D, but sometimes the implicit conversion confuse me. I believe, in that case, it instantiates an array of double, then tries to find a matching function, then tries to implicitly convert the array to fit in the function right? I believe the problem is the implicit conversion kills the static-ness of the array, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Try `1.0L`. That should force it to be some kind of array of `real`. and seeing if that works or not should give some more information.

Comment: @BCS I tried this, the error message was "cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(real[])", so clearly, I am only going to get a dynamic array from my literal, as Johnathan pointed out below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[1,2,3]` is not a static array. It's a dynamic array, so it *can't* match. It's the wrong type, and there's no way to have a static array literal. If you want to pass an array literal as a static array, you're going to need to either assign it to a variable first or cast it to the type that you want.

```
auto w = unit(cast(real[3])[1,2,3]);
```

should work. Personally, I'd argue that it's best to just explicitly instantiate the template

```
auto w = unit!3([1, 2, 3]);
```

because it avoids the risk of screwing up the cast.

Now, I think that there's a definite argument that the compiler should just work in this case, but it tends to be much pickier with templates than with normal functions, since it generally instantiates templates with the exact type that you pass it without trying to do any implicit conversions, whereas a normal function would implicitly convert the dynamic array to a static one. Feel free to [open an enhancement request](http://d.puremagic.com/issues). The behavior might get changed. It *was* recently changed so that IFTI (implicit function template instantiation) instantiates with the tail-const version of an array (e.g. `immutable(char)[]` instead of `immutable(char[])`), which has been a definite improvement. Now, that's a bit different than attempting a conversion (I believe that the compiler just automatically, always treats arrays as tail-const for IFTI), so I don't know that the odds of getting the compiler's behavior changed in this case are very high. But it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed answer and explanation. This is what I was beginning to suspect, but D is so flexible I couldn't decide whether I was simply overlooking some alternative syntax. In any case, I'm starting to think the array literals are more useful for my unit tests than anywhere else, and the "!n" is not that verbose. Thanks again!

Comment: D is very flexible, but things can get complicated with templates - particularly for the implementation. It would get very slow for the compiler to try every possible implicit conversion for every template, so it just uses the exact type. Some tweaks are possible (as with taking the tail-const versions of arrays), but there are limits. There are likely still places where IFTI could be improved though, and this case at least appears to be one of them.

Comment: I'll go ahead and submit the request, like you said, it can't hurt. I am honestly blown away by how many things "just make sense" in D. It's almost like it was designed intentionally!

Answer (score 2):

Idea/hack:

```
real[T.length] unit(T...)(T t)
{
    real[T.length] v,u;
    foreach(i,x; t) v[i] = x;
    u[] = (v[] / norm(v));
    return u;
}

void main()
{
    real[3] v = unit(1,2,3);
}
```

Might not be as fast as using `real[3] v = unit!3([1,2,3])` because of the foreach there, though, I suppose. Also the args gets converted to real at runtime. Hm.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. For my problem, I wanted to force static arrays of real for both input and output. Basically, I only wanted to allow for arbitrary length vectors, without allowing for mixed precision, dynamic length, uneven length (for binary functions), etc. I ended up using a mix of Johnathan's answer, for functions which generalized well, and just declaring four overloads for those that didn't (normSquared and dot). Thanks for your input!